# Clip raster by mask layer change the pixels size

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-3

I've a raster that have the pixels of this dimensions:

- x 0.2282548198093489467 m
- y 0.3594572165075641257 m

I need to clip this raster with a vector because I need a raster with the same extensions of vector.

I use QGIS 3.4 and the process `Clip Raster by Mask Layer` to do this. At the end of the process I have a raster with this pixels dimensions: 0.345 m.

Why happen this? I expect an output raster with the same pixels dimension of the input raster.

Comment: Did you enable the option `Keep resolution of input raster`?

Comment: I try to do this,  image size is 30GB, it take many time to have an output. Anyway, I think is not logic this because if I need to resize my pixels I can do it using a specific option, otherwise, I select the mask and nothing else.

Comment: @Joseph you are right. If you answer my question I can vote you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the GUI of the **Clip raster by mask layer** tool, you can enable the `Keep resolution of input raster` option to keep the size of the pixels used in the source file. You could also manually set the size using the option shown in the image (or use the `-tr` flag if using the command line):

[image: Clip raster by mask layer interface]